# How to test auto generated slug is unique?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

The system I am working with generates a [`slug`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug) from a `title` field. The `title` doesn't have to be unique however the `slug` does.

If the `slug` is determined to not be unique, the system generates a token to append to the end of the `slug` to make it unique.

As the `user` is not responsible for defining the `slug`, what's the recommended way of testing this workflow?

Is it sufficient to simply test that the same `slug` does not exist more than once in the database? So for example:

```
$title = 'Ships in the Night';

$a = Model::factory()->create(['title' => $title]);

$b = $this->post('/endpoint', ['title' => $title]);

$this->assertCount(1, Model::where('slug', $a->slug)->get());
$this->assertCount(1, Model::where('slug', $b->slug)->get());
```

Comment: Yes that looks sensible. However you should also specify that `slug` is a unique field in the database to make this stricter. This would remove the need for this test

Comment: @apokryfos I have also specified the field to be unique in the database. How does doing so remove the need for such a test?

Comment: Because if a duplicate slug is to be inserted there will be a DB exception raised so you'd just need to assert a 200 status without needing to do queries

Comment: @apokryfos that is not true, you test everything, if the DB has a unique field (really good approach) you still have to test if your system does have it, and if so, how it is handled (because an exception will be thrown). You have to test everything. Think that the user changes DB to Redis or something else, how can you test that anything you did in the DB still works ? You must have a test.